# Optmizing a regex-based lookup function

Tags: java, regex

I have the following function.

```
private boolean codeContains(String name, String code) {
    if (name == null || code == null) {
        return false;
    }

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(name) + "\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(code);

    return matcher.find();
}
```

It is called many thousand times in my code, and is the function in which my program spends the most amount of time in. Is there any way to make this function go faster, or is it already as fast as it can be?

Comment: We need context : is `code` reused ? Or are the two strings always different ?

Comment: Name will always be diffrent, code can in some cases be the same, but will change every once in a while. The code variable represents the contents of some file, and this function is used on multiple files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to check word boundaries, you might do this :

```
private boolean codeContains(String name, String code) {
    return name != null && code != null && code.indexOf(name)>=0;
}
```

If you need to check word boundaries but, as I suppose is your case, you have a big `code` in which you often search, you could "compile" the `code` once by

- splitting the `code` string using the split method
- putting the tokens in a HashSet (checking if a token is in a hashset is reasonably fast).

Of course, if you have more than one code, it's easy to store them in a structure adapted to your program, for example in a map having as key the file name.

Comment: This won't check for word-boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

"Plain" string operations will (almost) always be faster than regex, especially when you can't pre-compile the pattern.

Something like this would be considerably faster (with large enough `name` and `code` strings), assuming `Character.isLetterOrDigit(...)` suits your needs:

```
private boolean codeContains(String name, String code) {

    if (name == null || code == null || code.length() < name.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (code.equals(name)) {
        return true;
    }

    int index = code.indexOf(name);
    int nameLength = name.length();

    if (index < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (index == 0) {
        // found at the start
        char after = code.charAt(index + nameLength);
        return !Character.isLetterOrDigit(after);
    }
    else if (index + nameLength == code.length()) {
        // found at the end
        char before = code.charAt(index - 1);
        return !Character.isLetterOrDigit(before);
    }
    else {
        // somewhere inside
        char before = code.charAt(index - 1);
        char after = code.charAt(index + nameLength);
        return !Character.isLetterOrDigit(after) && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(before);
    }
}
```

And a small test succeeds:

```
@Test
public void testCodeContainsFaster() {

    final String code = "FOO some MU code BAR";

    org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(codeContains("FOO", code));
    org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(codeContains("MU", code));
    org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(codeContains("BAR", code));
    org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(codeContains(code, code));

    org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(codeContains("FO", code));
    org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(codeContains("BA", code));
    org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(codeContains(code + "!", code));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seemed to do it:

```
private boolean codeContains(String name, String code) {
    if (name == null || code == null || name.length() == 0 || code.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    int nameLength = name.length();
    int lastIndex = code.length() - nameLength;

    if (lastIndex < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int curr = 0; curr < lastIndex; ) {
        int index = code.indexOf(name, curr);
        int indexEnd = index + nameLength;

        if (index < 0 || lastIndex < index) {
            break;
        }

        boolean leftOk = index == curr ||
                index > curr && !Character.isAlphabetic(code.charAt(index - 1));

        boolean rightOk = index == lastIndex ||
                index < lastIndex && !Character.isAlphabetic(code.charAt(indexEnd));

        if (leftOk && rightOk) {
            return true;
        }

        curr += indexEnd;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The accepted answer goes to dystroy as he was the first to point me in the right direction, excellent answer by Bart Kiers though, +1!

Comment: Btw, for those interested. The original function, for my general usecase, tok 2.6s of the total runtime 3.6 (according to JVisualVM). The re-written function wasn't even listed in JVisualVM, but the total runtime was now 1.8s.